# Frozen columns in HTML table has transparent overlay over rest of table

Tags: html, css, html-table, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create two sticky columns that scroll horizontally through the tables. The first column behaves properly but the second column is transparent and sits on top of the other columns and rows in the table when you scroll. I've tried adjusting the padding and position properties but I cant seem to get my columns to scroll properly through the table.

I am using https://jsfiddle.net/zinoui/BmLpV/ as a reference.

```css
.zui-table {
    border: none;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: none;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.zui-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.zui-scroller {
    margin-left: 141px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}
.zui-table .zui-sticky-col1 {
    border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    width: 120px;
}

.zui-table .zui-sticky-col2 {
    border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    left: 20;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="zui-wrapper">
    <div class="zui-scroller">
        <table class="zui-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="zui-sticky-col1">Name</th>
                    <th class="zui-sticky-col2">Number</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Height</th>
                    <th>Born</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Prior to NBA/Country</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col1">DeMarcus Cousins</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col2">15</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>6'11"</td>
                    <td>08-13-1990</td>
                    <td>$4,917,000</td>
                    <td>Kentucky/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col1">Isaiah Thomas</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col2">22</td>
                    <td>PG</td>
                    <td>5'9"</td>
                    <td>02-07-1989</td>
                    <td>$473,604</td>
                    <td>Washington/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col1">Ben McLemore</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col2">16</td>
                    <td>SG</td>
                    <td>6'5"</td>
                    <td>02-11-1993</td>
                    <td>$2,895,960</td>
                    <td>Kansas/USA</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.zui-table .zui-sticky-col-next {
    border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    left: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    width: 50px;
}

.zui-table tbody td {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

then add the next class in each HTML Column:

```
<div class="zui-wrapper">
    <div class="zui-scroller">
        <table class="zui-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="zui-sticky-col">Name</th>
                    <th class="zui-sticky-col-next">Number</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Height</th>
                    <th>Born</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Prior to NBA/Country</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">DeMarcus Cousins</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col-next">15</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>6'11"</td>
                    <td>08-13-1990</td>
                    <td>$4,917,000</td>
                    <td>Kentucky/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Isaiah Thomas</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col-next">22</td>
                    <td>PG</td>
                    <td>5'9"</td>
                    <td>02-07-1989</td>
                    <td>$473,604</td>
                    <td>Washington/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Ben McLemore</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col-next">16</td>
                    <td>SG</td>
                    <td>6'5"</td>
                    <td>02-11-1993</td>
                    <td>$2,895,960</td>
                    <td>Kansas/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Marcus Thornton</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col-next">23</td>
                    <td>SG</td>
                    <td>6'4"</td>
                    <td>05-05-1987</td>
                    <td>$7,000,000</td>
                    <td>Louisiana State/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Jason Thompson</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col-next">34</td>
                    <td>PF</td>
                    <td>6'11"</td>
                    <td>06-21-1986</td>
                    <td>$3,001,000</td>
                    <td>Rider/USA</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.zui-table {
    border: none;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: none;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.zui-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.zui-scroller {
    margin-left: 141px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}
.zui-table .zui-sticky-col {
    border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    width: 120px;
}

.zui-table .zui-sticky-col-next {
    border-left: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    border-right: solid 1px #DDEFEF;
    left: 100;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    width: 50px;
}

.zui-table tbody td {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="zui-wrapper">
    <div class="zui-scroller">
        <table class="zui-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="zui-sticky-col">Name</th>
                    <th class="zui-sticky-col-next">Number</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Height</th>
                    <th>Born</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Prior to NBA/Country</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">DeMarcus Cousins</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col-next">15</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>6'11"</td>
                    <td>08-13-1990</td>
                    <td>$4,917,000</td>
                    <td>Kentucky/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Isaiah Thomas</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col-next">22</td>
                    <td>PG</td>
                    <td>5'9"</td>
                    <td>02-07-1989</td>
                    <td>$473,604</td>
                    <td>Washington/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Ben McLemore</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col-next">16</td>
                    <td>SG</td>
                    <td>6'5"</td>
                    <td>02-11-1993</td>
                    <td>$2,895,960</td>
                    <td>Kansas/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Marcus Thornton</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col-next">23</td>
                    <td>SG</td>
                    <td>6'4"</td>
                    <td>05-05-1987</td>
                    <td>$7,000,000</td>
                    <td>Louisiana State/USA</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col">Jason Thompson</td>
                    <td class="zui-sticky-col-next">34</td>
                    <td>PF</td>
                    <td>6'11"</td>
                    <td>06-21-1986</td>
                    <td>$3,001,000</td>
                    <td>Rider/USA</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This partially works. The locked column 'number' still covers up the 'position' column though. Do you think making a div of the locked columns and a relative div of the other columns would work? I tried doing this with a flex container but couldn't get the code right.

Comment: @KwesiC I think that could do the work, you can try as I will try as well

Comment: @KwesiC check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4e7scgxp/390/) Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try it, please

```
.zui-table tbody td {
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Upon a second look, I see that the 'position' column is actually covered up by the 'number' column. The frozen columns still overlap over the column.